# Asymptotic distribution of $S_n$

Tags: regression, self-study, econometrics, asymptotics

I am reviewing some exams from Hansen's webpage and came across this question that unfortunately doesn't have a suggested solution.

In the regression/projection model $$y_i=x_i'\beta+e_i$$ $$E(x_ie_i)=0$$ the asymptotic distribution for $\hat{\beta}$ is largely determined by that of $$S_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^nx_ie_i$$ The question asks what is the asymptotic distribution of $S_n$?

Can we state that if $x_ie_i$ is i.i.d, mean 0 and finite variance, through the CLT we can state that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^nx_ie_i\xrightarrow{d}\mathcal{N}(0,\Omega)$$

This comes from $$\sqrt{n}(\hat{\beta}-\beta)=(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_ix_i')^{-1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^nx_ie_i')$$ The random pairs ($y_ix_i$) is i.i.d so that means that every function is i.i.d, this includes $e_i=y_i-x_i'\beta$ and $x_ie_i$ where the latter is mean-zero $E[xe]=0$ and has $k \times k$ covariance matrix. $$\Omega=E[(xe)(xe)']=E[xx'e]$$

Then it asks to draw $n$ i.i.d $N(0, 1)$ random variables $u_i, i = 1, .., n$, independent of the sample. Define $$S_n^*=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^nx_ie_iu_i$$ What is the exact distribution of $S_n^*$, conditional on the sample? As $n\rightarrow\infty$, what is its asymptotic
distribution?

Comment: Can you give some more details about the assumptions? Are $\epsilon_i$ iid normal with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$ and are $x_i$ fixed bounded constants or are they  vectors or random variables?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: I added the tag. So for the first part, I guess it's explained in his book so there's not much to add there. Where I am stuck is in the second part where it asks for the distribution of $S_n^*$ specifically with $u_i$, I don't understand that.